# Fit user specified number of rows and columns to a given papersize

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to print out specified area (the number of columns and row is to be determined by the program itself based on the content of the sheet). To know how many row/columns can fit in the given paper size (11" x 8.5"), the straight forward method would be to get the total number of columns that can fit in the paper area (excluding left and right margin). I guess that the size of paper width is 11" -> 792 points (in landscape). The left and right margins are both 0.25" inch -> 18points. However when I add the width of all the columns it comes out to be just 222.86.

For testing purpose in the first page, the printable column should be from A:AE. I printed a pdf and it fits perfectly with scale of 55%.

I checked and got that range(A:AE) has a total width of 222.86. [I am not sure if unit of 222.86 is "points" or something else]

I cannot understand why the sum of (Lmargin, totalColumnWidth + Rmargin) is not equal to 792.
Does it have something to do with the scale, which is 55% in this case? If yes, can anyone please tell me how incorporate the scale factor in determining how many columns can fit in the predetermined paper size?

```
Sub GetPrintableAreaWidth()

    Dim pageSetup As pageSetup: Set pageSetup = ActiveSheet.pageSetup

    
    Dim totalWidth As Double: totalWidth = 0
    For i = 1 To 32
            totalWidth = totalWidth + Cells(1, i).columnWidth
    Next i

    Debug.Print pageSetup.LeftMargin, pageSetup.RightMargin
    Debug.Print totalWidth   
End Sub
```

```
outputs >>>

LeftMargin: 18
RightMargin: 18
totalWidth: 222.86
```

What is the exact number of POINTS that could fit in 100% scale level?

Comment: `columWidth` doesn't return the width in points, try `width` instead.